# What kind of soil do potted sensitivity plants need?

Tags: houseplants, soil, containers, potting-soil

I bought a sensitivity plant (Mimosa Pudica) and noticed it was planted in an unusual looking soil.  I want to transfer it to a larger container, so I would like to know how to buy or prepare a suitable potting medium.

According to [this site](http://www.ehow.com/info_7791625_soil-requirements-mimosa-pudica.html#ixzz2UPBvW3yG):

> The University of Oklahoma Department of Botany and Microbiology's
>   website Plant of the Week recommends using a potting mixture for
>   sensitive plant that consists of two parts peat moss, two parts loam
>   and one part sand or perlite, a formulation used to successfully grow
>   this plant. This mixture provides the good drainage that sensitive
>   plants need to thrive.

Is such a potting mixture or reasonably equivalent available for purchase?  If not, are the components readily available in stores?

Answer (score 2):

I've grown this successfully as a houseplant, but I never used any fancy or special compost, I just used a mix of John Innes No. 2 and multi purpose compost with a bit of added horticultural grit to increase drainage, and the plant was fine. (I haven't got it now because I let it get too cold, which isn't difficult in the UK).

The trick is drainage - this plant likes water (not so much in winter) but it must have free draining conditions, so as long as the pot has good drainage, the compost within is free draining, and you don't leave it standing in any outer tray or pot which has water in it, it should be fine.